# How to update pdf using syncfusion in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, pdf

I am new in Flutter and use syncfusion pkg to modify PDF.

First, I am trying to add one table in pdf by attaching a new page to the existing pdf as follows:

```
PdfDocument document = PdfDocument(inputBytes: file.readAsBytesSync());

int pageCount = document.pages.count;
document.pages.insert(pageCount + 1);
PdfPage page = document.pages[pageCount];

PdfGrid grid = PdfGrid();
grid.columns.add(count: 2);
grid.headers.add(1);
PdfGridRow header = grid.headers[0];
header.cells[0].value = 'Signed BY';
header.cells[1].value = 'Date';
PdfGridRow row = grid.rows.add();
row.cells[0].value = userName;
row.cells[1].value = formattedDate;
grid.style = PdfGridStyle(
   cellPadding: PdfPaddings(left: 2, right: 3, top: 4, bottom: 5),
   backgroundBrush: PdfBrushes.white,
   textBrush: PdfBrushes.black,
   font: PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.timesRoman, 20));
grid.draw(page: page,bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(10, 30, 400, 300));

File('${directory.path}/$fileName').writeAsBytes(await document.save());
File fileToUpdate = File("${directory.path}/$fileName");
```

Now What I want again read that updated PDF go to the last page find out that table and add a new row to an existing table.

Currently, I am try to do this using the below code but it does not work for me

```
PdfDocument document = PdfDocument(inputBytes: file.readAsBytesSync());
int pageCount = document.pages.count;
PdfPage page = document.pages[pageCount - 1];
PdfGrid grid = PdfGrid();
PdfGridRow row = grid.rows.add();
row.cells[0].value = userName;
row.cells[1].value = formattedDate;
grid.style = PdfGridStyle(
   cellPadding: PdfPaddings(left: 2, right: 3, top: 4, bottom: 5),
   backgroundBrush: PdfBrushes.white,
   textBrush: PdfBrushes.black,
   font: PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.timesRoman, 15));
grid.draw(page: page,bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(10, 320, 400, 300));

File('${directory.path}/$fileName').writeAsBytes(await document.save());
File fileToUpdate = File("${directory.path}/$fileName");
```

How to do that any idea? or What changes I required in the above code?

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.